# Problem with titledquestion in exam document class

Tags: titles, exam, points

I have titled and notitled question in my document, also I'm using ifthen package, but in notitled questions, there are numbers in square brackets. How can I get rid of them??

My document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\thequestion}{\thequestiontitle}}
        {}
        } 
        {~{\small [\thequestiontitle]}}
    \hfill
\textsl{(\thepoints)}}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}
\pointname{\ p}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\titledquestion{Title}[5] The first question

\question[3] My question

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Move one of the `}` slightly: ... `{}
        {~{\small [\thequestiontitle]}}
        } 
    \hfill`...

Comment: Yes, that fix my problem, but I dont want to have bold question title.

Comment: Put the `}` of `\textbf{...}` where you want the bold to end. Originally you had it in the middle of `ifthenelse`, pushing what was intended to be the false part outside the ifthenelse. E,g.,  try ...`\thequestion .}`...

Comment: Yes, now it is exactly as I wanted. thank you very much